# Is there a software to control my wireless router?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

I was a **windows** user and was controlling my router using ***selfishnet*** and now I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 , 
I wonder if there is a similar software or any other way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Many wireless routers can be controlled from your browser. When you are connected to your router, try each of the following IP's. They are all local IPs, and it depends on how your network is setup that determines which one will work.

- http://10.0.0.1/
- http://192.168.1.1/
- http://192.168.0.1/

If these do not work, find your local IP address using the following command:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | grep -v 127.0.0.1
```

My output is like this:

```
inet addr:10.0.0.9  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Change the last set of four digits after the `inet addr:` to a 1, and put that in your browser.

My local IP is `10.0.0.9`, so my router would be at `10.0.0.1` (most likely).

If none of these work, your router may not support configuration over a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can install [Net Line Dancer](http://logicvein.com/) most network developer use it you can

1. Copy the installer (**netLD-2013.08.0-x86_64.bin**) on the target server.
2. Run `chmod +x netLD-2013.08.0-x86_64.bin` and change permission of the installer copied.
3. Run `sudo ./ netLD-2013.08.0-x86_64.bin` and execute installation.
4. When Is this ok **[y/N]**: is displayed, enter **y** and proceed next step.
5. Create SSL certificate. When Overwrite **[y/n]**: is displayed, enter **y** and enter the information of SSL certificate within the red frame.
6. Enter the license key at Activation Serial or License File:Ex) `E9A6D-02FD6-C4158-92FB4-EA739`
7. Installation has finished and the service of netLD starts.

for more guides check this [installation guide](https://logicvein.com/product/pdf/Install_Guide_for_Linux.pdf).