# Selfishnet alternative for ubuntu

Tags: internet

Is there any alternative to Selfishnet program for ubuntu , 
or there are any way i can limit the speed of internet to the other PCs 
on my network ?

If there are a program with GUI it'll be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a software to control my wireless router?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/780060/is-there-a-software-to-control-my-wireless-router)

Comment: I was having the same question...
Have you tried to use Selfishnet via VMware or VirtualBox? I am not sure if it can work...

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively new and currently maintained project called `evillimiter` it uses "ARP spoofing", same as selfishnet and netcut and all these "ugly" limiters you can find it here https://github.com/bitbrute/evillimiter, if you are using Arch or any Arch-based distro you can find it in the AUR however it is not a well maintained package so i highly recommend to clone it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Mastershaper**](https://github.com/unki/MasterShaper):

> Websolution for Linux network traffic shaping and QoS with iproute2.